# Android Google Map couldn't find classcom.google.android.gms.location.internal.parcelableGeofence

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on Android apps with `google-map-v2`. Recently I edited this app to fix some word and at the time worked perfectly. After I rebooted my Android device now the app crashes in "MapActivity". I've made many tests, re-factoring the phone, updated "Google Play Services" on the phone, re-installed with the latest adt and avd on Win7 64bit, updated SHA1 key, and it is still not working if I turn location off on my phone. The phone asks to enable it and my map works, but if I try again with location enable the app crashes in "MapActivity" again. Here is my code:

```
package com.gekim360.map;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.gekim360.cart.SendOrderList;
import com.gekim360.gridhour.MainHourActivity;
import com.gekim360.log.Login;
import com.gekim360.storeinfo.ShowInfoActivity;
import com.gekim360.tap.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "App";

private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://xxxxxx/xxxxx/map.php";
private void setUpMap() {
    // Retrieve the city data from the web service
    // In a worker thread since it's a network operation.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                retrieveAndAddCities();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive cities", e);
                return;
            }
        }
    }).start();
 }

protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Connect to the web service
        URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            json.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
        throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // Create markers for the city data.
    // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
            }
        }
    });
}

void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
            .snippet(jsonObj.getString("name"))
            .position(new LatLng(
                    jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                    jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
             ))
        );
    }
 }
 Dialog dialog;
 protected GoogleMap googleMap;
 String phone_id,TAG_LOCALE;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
     Intent i = getIntent();
      phone_id = i.getStringExtra("phone_id");
      TAG_LOCALE = i.getStringExtra("language_id");            
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service
      .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

     // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
     // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to 
     // go to the settings
     if (!enabled) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
     // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available   

       setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

  }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

  }

 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
     if (googleMap == null) {
         googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
         // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
         LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

         // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (googleMap != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
            setUpMap();
         }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
     }
     googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener( new OnMarkerClickListener(){


                @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    // Show a Spinner progressDialog
                    ProgressDialog.show(
                      MapActivity.this,       // Activity Context
                      "",  // Dialog Title, if left blank no title is shown
                      "Loading...",  // Message To Display
                      false,         // Spinner Style
                      true           // Cancelable
                    );
                    String store = marker.getTitle();
                  Intent nextStore = new Intent(MapActivity.this,ShowInfoActivity.class);
                  String phone = phone_id.toString();
                  nextStore.putExtra("store_id", store);
                  nextStore.putExtra("phone_id", phone);
                    nextStore.putExtra("language_id", TAG_LOCALE);
                    startActivityForResult(nextStore, 0);

                return false; 
            }
          } 
        );
  }



  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

     // Getting latitude of the current location
     double latitude = location.getLatitude();

     // Getting longitude of the current location
     double longitude = location.getLongitude();        

     // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

     // Showing the current location in Google Map
     googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
     googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
     tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );     

  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
 }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
     return true;
  }
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

 super.onBackPressed();
 Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, Login.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent); 
 finish();
 }
 }
```

my xml file :

```
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

my manifest file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.gekim360.tap"
 android:versionCode="3"
 android:versionName="1.1" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <permission android:name="com.gekim360.tap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"       android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.gekim360.tap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>  
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx" />  
        <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <activity android:name="com.gekim360.log.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>                           
           </activity> 
                       <activity android:name="com.gekim360.log.Register"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>  
                                   <activity android:name="com.gekim360.log.Registered"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity> 
                                   <activity android:name="com.gekim360.log.ChangePassword"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>   
                                   <activity android:name="com.gekim360.log.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>  
                                   <activity android:name="com.gekim360.log.PasswordReset"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>  
                                   <activity android:name="com.gekim360.log.FirstUserEditForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>  

                    <activity android:name="com.gekim360.userdata.UserAdressEditForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>  
                                <activity android:name="com.gekim360.tapandsnack.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>
                    <activity android:name="com.gekim360.map.DashboardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity> 

        <activity android:name="com.gekim360.userdata.ToStayActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>               
                                <activity android:name="com.gekim360.map.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">  
        </activity>
```

my  proguard project.txt :

```
 -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
 protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
 public static final *** NULL;
 }

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
 @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final ** CREATOR;
 }
```

my logcat :

```
09-01 23:23:37.001: W/dalvikvm(28286): VFY: unable to resolve static method 24934: Lgui;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgrh;
09-01 23:23:37.017: E/dalvikvm(28286): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-01 23:23:37.017: W/dalvikvm(28286): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-01 23:23:37.017: E/dalvikvm(28286): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-01 23:23:37.017: W/dalvikvm(28286): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-01 23:23:37.017: E/dalvikvm(28286): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-01 23:23:37.017: W/dalvikvm(28286): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-01 23:23:37.048: W/dalvikvm(28286): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
09-01 23:23:37.048: W/dalvikvm(28286): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
09-01 23:23:37.447: W/dalvikvm(28286): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
09-01 23:23:37.447: E/dalvikvm(28286): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
09-01 23:23:37.447: W/dalvikvm(28286): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;
09-01 23:23:37.572: W/dalvikvm(28286): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cba930)
09-01 23:23:37.587: E/AndroidRuntime(28286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 23:23:37.587: E/AndroidRuntime(28286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.gekim360.tap/com.gekim360.map.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: today i tried my apps away from home and start to work with no logcat warning with and without location activited but still need to know why ,,is it my phone ,the link of google play or my provider give me a  hint please ,next i will try on other phone

Comment: finnaly my problem is due to the place where i'm working the gps can't define  my place exactly, i just need to walk around it start to work and keep me  healthy